# Flagged message not coloring subject as expected

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007

When I red flagged a message in my Inbox the whole subject line used to turn red then about six months ago it just stopped doing that.

I found it extremely useful because it made messages I wanted to keep or answer very visible.

How can I set it up again?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. When you flag a message are you adding a due date? It doesn't turn read unless it is past due.

Comment: Thank you.  I maybe didn't make it clear that I'm referring to received messages in my Inbox.  I never did anything before other than click the red marker to remind me not to delete the message.
I can't add a 'due date' because sometimes I don't know how long I want to keep it.  I have started using the categories but it's not as satisfactory as the whole subject line turning red.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you had conditional formatting set up for your Inbox view that colored flagged messages red. For some reason this setting was lost. You can add it back any time by opening **View Settings -> Conditional Formatting...**. There, you can set the **Font** as you like (including color) and **Add** a new condition and on **More Choices** tab, set **Only items which are flagged by me**.

Comment: Thank you.  I have looked everywhere for the things you suggest but I don't ssem to have any of those options.  (Windows 7, Home Premium, Outlook 2007.)

Comment: In Outlook 2007 it's the Organize feature (you can find it in the menu). Look here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Automatically-change-incoming-message-colors-and-fonts-based-on-sender-subject-or-recipients-4efbf993-fb00-4f2c-9a3f-78e64e4455ec

Comment: Thank you so much.  I have done it which I would never have managed without your help.